# Jquery not working on codepen

Tags: javascript, jquery, codepen

I'm a beginner in coding and I would really appreciate some help.
My jquery doesnt work in codepen. I've tried adding jquery in the settings bar, and it still doesnt work.
I actually added my jquery to the top of my html section in codepen inside of script tags.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("h2").addClass("animated bounce");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what is the error message? can you provide a screenshot that shows how you added jquery exactly and/or more of your code.

Comment: @Hikarunomemory i've tried adding it and it doesnt work

Comment: where is the codepen?

Comment: @fastr.de it doesnt allow me to upload photos here but i went to settings, on javacript i added both jquery and jquery UI and it still doesnt work

Comment: you're going to add 2 classes or just 1?

Comment: https://codepen.io/aabla/pen/aYYOxy/ @gaetanoM

Comment: @Hikarunomemory well i wanted to make sure it works so i tried animated bounce just like in freecodecamp lesson. i believe that is considered 2 classes since they're separated with a spacebar

Comment: take a look to the [updated one](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmQYXK)

Comment: @gaetanoM it worked! thank you so much! so I can just add that function to javascript instead of html ^^ Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your HTML window to load JQuery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Not sure how codepen works, but normally when you want to use JQuery, you would download the JQuery file and then load the file locally, like this:

```
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Or use this code if your not working from a local machine or if you just don't want to download it:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.